# Android GridView loading images from bottom to top issue

Tags: android, gridview, asynchronous

I am using the GridView to show images and loading this images in asynchronous manner. Everything is working proper only the problem is the images are loaded in GridView from bottom  to top, instead of top to bottom. Really unable to understand how to solve this issue.
Please help me on this issue.

EDIT1:
GridView Adapter code:

```
public class ImageThumbAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Activity context;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mImageList;
        private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        private int mItemHeight = 0;
        private int mNumColumns = 0;
        private GridView.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

        public ImageThumbAdapter(Activity c,
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imageList) {
            context = c;
            mImageList = imageList;
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
            mImageViewLayoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mImageList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public void addImage(HashMap<String, String> image) {
            mImageList.add(image);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            // Now handle the main ImageView thumbnails
            ImageView imageView;

            if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, instantiate and
                                        // initialize
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            } 
            else { // Otherwise re-use the converted view
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            if (imageView.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
                imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            }

            String imageName = String.format(
                    "gallery_",
                    mImageList.get(position).get(TAG_THUMB_URL));

            imageView.setTag(imageName);
            mImageLoader.setDefualtStub(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail);

            mImageLoader.DisplayImage(
                    mImageList.get(position).get(TAG_THUMB_URL), context,
                    imageView, imageName, new ImageLoadingListener());

            return imageView;
        }

        ....

    }
```

Edit2:
Logs for position

```
08-10 23:16:23.132: I/System.out(785): Position: 0
08-10 23:16:23.142: I/System.out(785): Position: 0
08-10 23:16:23.142: I/System.out(785): Position: 1
08-10 23:16:23.152: I/System.out(785): Position: 2
08-10 23:16:23.152: I/System.out(785): Position: 3
08-10 23:16:23.152: I/System.out(785): Position: 4
08-10 23:16:23.162: I/System.out(785): Position: 5
08-10 23:16:23.162: I/System.out(785): Position: 6
08-10 23:16:23.162: I/System.out(785): Position: 7
08-10 23:16:23.172: I/System.out(785): Position: 8
08-10 23:16:23.172: I/System.out(785): Position: 9
08-10 23:16:23.172: I/System.out(785): Position: 10
08-10 23:16:23.182: I/System.out(785): Position: 11
08-10 23:16:23.182: I/System.out(785): Position: 12
08-10 23:16:23.192: I/System.out(785): Position: 13
08-10 23:16:23.192: I/System.out(785): Position: 14
08-10 23:16:23.192: I/System.out(785): Position: 15
08-10 23:16:23.312: D/dalvikvm(785): GC_EXPLICIT freed 434K, 20% free 9440K/11655K, paused 5ms+5ms
08-10 23:16:23.322: D/ImageLoader(785): gallery_http:%0%0s3.amazonaws.com%0DEV_ALC_USRDATA%013222763351652338265%0cms_Gallery%02x_1342687302114.143.121.36Apple-icon.gif.jpg Image doesn't exits in cache
08-10 23:16:23.322: D/ImageLoader(785): gallery_http:%0%0s3.amazonaws.com%0DEV_ALC_USRDATA%013222763351652338265%0cms_Gallery%02x_1342687302114.143.121.36Apple-icon.gif.jpg Downloading from server
08-10 23:16:23.902: D/dalvikvm(785): GC_EXPLICIT freed 98K, 19% free 9502K/11655K, paused 5ms+5ms
08-10 23:16:23.902: I/System.out(785): Position: 0
08-10 23:16:23.912: I/System.out(785): Position: 0
08-10 23:16:23.932: D/ImageLoader(785): igallery_http:%0%0s3.amazonaws.com%0DEV_ALC_USRDATA%013222763351652338265%0cms_Gallery%02x_1342687299114.143.121.3627.png.jpg Image doesn't exits in cache
08-10 23:16:23.952: D/ImageLoader(785): igallery_http:%0%0s3.amazonaws.com%0DEV_ALC_USRDATA%013222763351652338265%0cms_Gallery%02x_1342687299114.143.121.3627.png.jpg Downloading from server
08-10 23:16:25.202: D/dalvikvm(785): GC_EXPLICIT freed 110K, 18% free 9614K/11655K, paused 4ms+6ms
08-10 23:16:25.212: I/System.out(785): Position: 0
08-10 23:16:25.222: I/System.out(785): Position: 0
08-10 23:16:25.242: D/ImageLoader(785): igallery_http:%0%0s3.amazonaws.com%0DEV_ALC_USRDATA%013222763351652338265%0cms_Gallery%02x_1342572563101.98.165.177bleyendall.png.jpg Image doesn't exits in cache
08-10 23:16:25.262: D/ImageLoader(785): igallery_http:%0%0s3.amazonaws.com%0DEV_ALC_USRDATA%013222763351652338265%0cms_Gallery%02x_1342572563101.98.165.177bleyendall.png.jpg Downloading from server
08-10 23:16:26.122: D/dalvikvm(785): GC_EXPLICIT freed 89K, 17% free 9691K/11655K, paused 4ms+5ms
08-10 23:16:26.122: I/System.out(785): Position: 0
08-10 23:16:26.132: I/System.out(785): Position: 0

...
```

Thanks,

Comment: Would you mind posting your code?

Comment: @javaMe nope. Added adapter code.

Comment: Can you add a log like `Log.d("ImageThumbAdapter", "Loading image: " + position)` and then share the Log output? Maybe the `getView` method will be called on the lower positions first for whatever reason.

Comment: @mercutio updated with position logs. As i see initially positions values are proper but later during download of images it logs as '0'. Is any problem with my ImageLoader?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem until I discovered the stackFromBottom attribute of the gridview.

In the xml of your gridview, put:

```
android:stackFromBottom="false"
```